How reset dimension of login windows
how reset dimension of login windows? See image!


Right click the window title, then choose size, then left-click on the edge of the window (just outside of it) and move the mouse (while clicked) to resize. Note that the mouse icon will NOT change to a "resize" icon as it usually does.

